# How to determine the names and types of the properties in a propertybusinessobject in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to retrieve the names and the types of the properties in a property business object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called introspection:

```
PropertyBusinessObject pb = ...;
PropertyIndex idx = pb.getPropertyIndex();
for(PropertyBase b : idx) {
    String propertyName = b.getName();
    Class type = b.getGenericType();
    //...
}
```